# How to sort an array by value in a certain order?

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array of any size (from 1 to 4 rounds) with ranks numbering from 1 to 8 (or more), how can I take that array and sort it bracket style, so rank 1 is first, rank 2 is last, then rank 8 is next, then rank 7 is second to last... like

Then the next round ..

1, 4, 3, 2

I am trying to sort tournament brackets but not having much luck when it comes to sorting the ranking, and also in a way that scales well so the display does not break.

**Edit**:

Some clarification, each bracket size needs to break down like so:

If the bracket has 8 games, the game numbers are 1 through 8, so that round needs to arrange itself like:

- Game 1
- Game 8
- Game 5
- Game 4
- Game 6
- Game 3
- Game 7
- Game 2

So then, on the next round, it has 4 games, which would come out as:

- Game 1
- Game 4
- Game 3
- Game 2

And so on:

- Game 1
- Game 2

Finally,

- Game 1

It also needs to work if the starting bracket had 16 games instead of 8, or 32, or more. The idea is that the winner of Game 1 and Game 8 play each other in Game 1 on the next round. The first game and second game are always the first and last on each bracket. Then it works it's way inward.

Comment: usort can help you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Thats the road I was going down, but did not understand how to sort them. If $a is 1 and $b is 2, what do you do?

Comment: You should have checked your post right after posting it, the order you posted now differs from the one you posted yesterday evening, the so far given answers are therefore useless and wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't sorting the list. Unless you really need to sort the list, indices may be faster and more efficient.

The match ups will be set up like `(current_rank), (total ranks) - (current_rank) + 1`

Since there are 8 ranks,

```
1, 8 -1 +1 = 8
2, 8 -2 +1 = 7
3, 8 -3 +1 = 6
4, 8 -4 +1 = 5
```

So the code would look *something* like

```
<?php
    $rankscount = count($ranks);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $rankscount / 2; $i++) {
        echo "matchup will be: rank " . $i . " , rank " . $rankscount - $i + 1;
    }
?>
```

After each round, reseed the function with the new sorted list, and you'll get 1vs4. 2vs3.
I'm not a professional at PHP, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: This is kind of close, but for a round with 8 games, it needs to go in this order: Game 1, Game 8, Game 5, Game 4, Game 6, Game 3, Game 7, Game 2. Then, the next bracket with 4 rounds would be: Game 1, Game 4, Game 3, Game 2.

Comment: @Kevin: The example you give differs from what you explain here. What is the order you need now?

Comment: Updated original question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The following function sorts an array of `['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6', 'r7', 'r8']` into an order of `['r1', 'r8', 'r2', 'r7', 'r3', 'r6', 'r4', 'r5']`.
An array of `['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4']` will be rearranged into `['r1', 'r4', 'r2', 'r3']`

```
function rearranged($array) {
    sort($array);
    $result = array();
    $length = count($array);
    $offset = 0;
    // Handling two elements at once, therefore just do $lenght/2 iterations
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length/2; $i++) {
        // $i + $offset: The current element in the original array 
        // + the offset of fields already filled in the results array
        $result[$i + $offset] = $array[$i];
        // $i + 1 + $offset: The next element in the results array
        $result[$i + 1 + $offset] = $array[$length - $i -1];
            // Increment offset
        $offset++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I am not using any inbuilt `sort` function since they compare all keys to each others, assuming that your array already is in order just iterating and swapping positions should be much faster. If the keys are not ordered you can call a inbuilt `sort` function such as `sort`(sorts by value) or `ksort` (sorts by key).

To note is as well, that this function only works properly for `arrays` with an even amount of elements. If the number of elements is uneven the last element will be dropped from the results array.